# django rest_framework select foreignKey model in CreateAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create new `ServiceArea` instance using **django rest framework**, but can't figure out how to set a `supplier` foreignKey field in `CreateApiView`. I'm trying to do it using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, but when i set `queryset` attribute equals to `Supplier.objects.all()` it gives error `'ServiceArea' object has no attribute 'suppliers'`. How i can get access to `suppliers` in `CreateApiView`? My code:

models.py

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=60)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Почта')
    phone_number = models.CharField('Номер телефона', max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField('Адрес центрального офиса', max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Поставщик'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Поставщики'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ServiceArea(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название области', max_length=120)
    poly = geo_models.PolygonField('Область', null=True)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, related_name='areas', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Сервисная зона'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Сервисные зоны'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
class SupplierSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        fields = [
            'id',
       ]

class ServiceAreaSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    suppliers = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Supplier.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = ServiceArea
        geo_field = 'poly'
        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
            'suppliers',
        ]
```

views.py

```
class ServiceAreaListApiView(ListAPIView, CreateAPIView):
    queryset = ServiceArea.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceAreaSerializer
```

Comment: what is your intent on using `null=True` in 'supplier' attribute of ServiceArea model?

Comment: @RaghavMittal i forgot to remove it. Used it to provide default values for  migration, because do not want to delete existing service areas while development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  `ServiceAreaSerializer` serializer the attribute name should be `supplier` and not `suppliers` because in `ServiceArea` class in the model, the attribute is `supplier` which contains the foreign key. The fields in model and serializer must match.

Comment: `Error: 'Supplier' object is not iterable.`
I figure out my problem. In `ServiceAreaSerializer`, i just add to `class Meta` following line: `fields = '__all__'`, and after this in CreateApiView i can to select `supplier` for `servicearea` instance.

Comment: @MaximZemskov Nice. I hope I was helpful.